# correct matrix to draw mesh as flat object

Tags: camera, monogame, matrix, rendertexture

I need to draw a tilemap for a 2d game. For that I created vertices with their relative positions already hard baked. The coordinates start top-left with (0f, 0f) and z is always 0.

I rendered them to the `rendertarget` with the following view matrix (world and projection are both `Identity`):

```
Matrix view = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(this.miniMapRenderTarget.Width, this.miniMapRenderTarget.Height, 0, 1)
     * Matrix.CreateScale((float)(this.miniMapRenderTarget.Width / (this.map.Size.X * this.map.TileSize.X * 2)))
     * Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
```

I noticed that all stuff was just rendered to the top-right quadrant of the texture so I added a translation of -0.5 for x and y. This works find, so far.

The only bug still is that Y seem to be displayed inverted, so top is bottom. I tried to fix this by multiplying `Matrix.CreateScale(1, -1, 1)` to the matrix but then I do not see anything rendered to the texture. I guess I am doing something fundamentally wrong here and the matrix has to be constructed in a different way?

Comment: When you reverse the Y, you also flip the winding order of the polygons, so front-facing polygons become back-facing. So you need to switch the culling mode (or turn off backface culling entirely)

Comment: @DMGregory: thx for the answer it seems to work now. i needed to set the cullmode and also ensure that the scale it multiplied at the end. but isn't there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: If you've solved your problem, post your corrected code as an Answer below. Folks can offer alternative answers, vote, and comment to give additional feedback about what solutions they think are simplest.

Comment: I would love to present an alternative answer as DMGregory suggested, but the offending lines of code(vertex type and definitions) are not given. If "baked" the load lines may be more appropriate, to allow a single fixed transform at the source.Or the draw line to correct the problem each step, poor solution, but better than rendering twice.

Comment: "or that I created vertices with their relative positions already hard baked. " un-bake them. and fix the problem at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by DMGregory, setting cullmode to none ensures that the inverted Y axis by scaling does not cull away objects. **Note: It would be even better to just invert the cullmode, e.g. setting it to counterclockwise when it was clockwise and vice versa.**

```
    this.graphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;     

    var view = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(this.miniMapRenderTarget.Width, this.miniMapRenderTarget.Height, 0, 1)               
         * Matrix.CreateTranslation(-1, -1, 0)
         * Matrix.CreateScale(1, -1, 1);
```

I would have preferred a solution that does not enforce modifying the cullmode but at least it works now.

Comment: You can change the winding of your polygons instead to compensate for the reflection in the matrix. Swapping two indices in every triangle will do the trick.

Comment: "setting cullmode to none" draws every triangle twice. Very poor solution. It may work, but it halves the rendering speed on non-workstation graphics cards. Fix the underlying problem, the workaround is not a viable scalable solution.

Comment: @Strom: As I wrote, also just inverting the Cullmode does the trick, e.g. setting to counterclockwise when it was clockwise and vice versa. If you now an even better solution please let me now.

Comment: @Strom it is not true that setting cullmode to none draws every triangle twice. It still draws them at most once per draw call. It just does not *abort* rendering of triangles that face away from the camera. If you have a 3D object with both a front & back side, this means two *different* triangles overlap each pixel, with the front one usually hiding the one behind, so it would've been safe to skip. That's what people mean when they say it doubles the work. It does not apply to a case like this where the object being drawn is only a single layer of polygons, with no back-facing skin to hide.

Comment: @DMGregory My point was to avoid `culllmode.none`  because it will incur a performance penalty, no matter the implementation.

Comment: @Strom: Oh damn it, I wrote slower in my comment instead of faster :) I deleted my comment. this is what I intended to write: cullmode.none can actually be faster if you know before, that all triangles are facing the camera (as in a 2d tile map), since the other culling modes both needs to perform the culling check, while "none" doesn't.